# Same session shared by two browsers? How can this be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I tried to set the session store to be a ActiveRecordStore. I have made the following changes:

```
# application.rb
config.action_dispatch.session_store = :active_record_store

# session_store.rb
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
ActiveRecord::SessionStore.session_class = Session

# the session class
class Session < ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :ensure_user_is_set

  def self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
    find(:first,"session_id = ?",session_id)
  end

  private
  def ensure_user_is_set
    warden_data = self.data["warden.user.user.key"]
    if warden_data
      user_id   = warden_data[1][0]
      self.user = User.find(user_id)
    end
  end
end
```

I opened 2 browsers ( a Firefox and a Chrome ). The very strange thing is that if I start
a `rails console`, and I write: `Session.count`, I get back `1`.

Afterwards, I login in Firefox, and then I refresh Chrome. Now both browsers appear as logged in. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't each browser have it's own session?

EDIT: It seems that my custom Session class is causing the problems. However, I'm not sure why.

EDIT 2: The problem was here:

```
  def self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
    find(:first,"session_id = ?",session_id)
  end
```

and it should have been:

```
  def self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
    find(:first,:conditions => ["session_id = ?",session_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
  def self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
    find(:first,"session_id = ?",session_id)
  end
```

and it should have been:

```
  def self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
    find(:first,:conditions => ["session_id = ?",session_id])
  end
```